# How to replace values of a SQL table with the previous data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table with a lot of results of a simulation, and I need to normalise my results by +-10%. I would like to be able to do this from a query; that is, each column value is multiplied by a random value between 0.9 and 1.1.

My table has the following form:

| id_result | parameter_a | parameter_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 358.02 | 0.115 |
| 2 | 357.31 | 0.052 |
| 3 | 320.89 | 0.233 |
| 4 | 387.11 | 0.011 |

The result would be that each result of columns parameter_a and parameter_b would be replace by itself * random between 0.9 and 1.1.
This would be:

| id_result | parameter_a | parameter_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 358.02 * RANDOM(0.9;1.1) | 0.115 * RANDOM(0.9;1.1) |
| 2 | 357.31 * RANDOM(0.9;1.1) | 0.052 * RANDOM(0.9;1.1) |
| 3 | 320.89 * RANDOM(0.9;1.1) | 0.233 * RANDOM(0.9;1.1) |
| 4 | 387.11 * RANDOM(0.9;1.1) | 0.011 * RANDOM(0.9;1.1) |

Does anyone know how to do this with an SQL query?

Comment: What's your expected result from your sample data? and why would you want to do `replace by itself * random between 0.9 and 1.1.`

Comment: I want to have the table with values in each cell +-10% with respect to their current value. It is a fairly large table, and I want to do it because it is confidential data so I need to be able to show it without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qq3nw4g2qEQdKQjYKfXget/0), but RAND() will do most of the work here:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    parameter_a * (0.9 + RAND() * 0.2) AS parameter_a_rand,
    parameter_b * (0.9 + RAND() * 0.2) AS parameter_b_rand
FROM test;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [RAND()](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_rand.asp) should achieve what you are looking for:

```sql
SELECT id_result, parameter_a * (RAND() * 2 + 9) / 10,  parameter_b * (RAND() * 2 + 9) / 10
```